# Passing matrix line to function, C

Tags: c, function, matrix

I have a matrix (2-dimensional array) and would want to send the values of a certain line to a function.

For example:

If I have the matrix `players[10][50]` then, how can I pass only players[0][0...50]?

Comment: `players[0]` would be a 1 dimensional array.

Comment: int my_function(int players[]) and my_function(players[0]) would work?

Comment: Yes but the function must somehow know the number of elements. It cant do that only by reference to the array passed.

Comment: To begin, if you dimensioned your array with a value of 50, trying to access element 50 will be a bug!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What type has an entry of the outer dimension of a 2D array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this using pointers...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArrayRow(int * row, int rowSize)
{
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<rowSize; i++)
    printf("%d ",row[i]);

  printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int data[4][4] = {{0,1,2,3},
                    {1,2,3,4},
                    {2,3,4,5},
                    {3,4,5,6}};

  printArrayRow(data[1], 4);
}
```

Comment: Using arrays for the parameters would be the same, but more self-documenting. But we don't do homework. A short hint would have been better.